# Find similar text from different cells and put them in a table

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a list of invitees but the names are in different columns. I would like to find all the names and put them in 1 column. For example:

***Here's an example of the list:***
[image]

I would like this sheet to turn into this:

***Results:***
[image]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try below array formula-

```
=INDEX($C$2:$E$6,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$6,0),MIN(INDEX(IF($C$2:$E$6<>"",COLUMN($C$2:$E$6)-COLUMN($B$2),""),MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$6,0))))
```

Enter the formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,C2:E2)`.  This will also put multiple names in a comma delimited list if for some reason your data has multiple names on the same row.